# How to add google map in bootstrap modal

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, google-maps

I am using Google Embed map option to insert a map into Bootstrap Modal, but the modal shows up with the shape of the map present, but only part of the map is displayed, the rest is gray.

Here is code i have used:

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Click For Map</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here jquery i have attached

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', (function() {
  var mapIsAdded = false;

  return function() {
    if (!mapIsAdded) {
      $('.modal-body').html('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d9808.974038062652!2d4.3244048859985185!3d52.07529689519739!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1snl!2snl!4v1419588821379" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>');

      mapIsAdded = true;
    }    
  };
})());
```

I am not able find out the exact problem for this , any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It has to do with the modal being `display: none` initially. I think this makes the Google Maps JavaScript inside the `iframe` unable to work properly. To see for yourself try removing the `.modal` class and open the modal.

The easiest solution might be to inject the iframe when the modal is opened for the first time, using the `shown.bs.modal` event:

```
$('#myModal').on('shown.bs.modal', (function() {
  var mapIsAdded = false;

  return function() {
    if (!mapIsAdded) {
      $('.modal-body').html('<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d9808.974038062652!2d4.3244048859985185!3d52.07529689519739!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1snl!2snl!4v1419588821379" width="100%" height="400" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>');

      mapIsAdded = true;
    }    
  };
})());
```

or see this <kbd>**[Codepen](http://codepen.io/ckuijjer/pen/azmVXG?editors=101)**</kbd>

Next to this the `iframe` has a fixed `width="800"` attribute. I would suggest you to change this into `width="100%"` as the modal window doesn't have a fixed width.

Comment: sorry to write this i have changed width to 100%, thats working fine but the below part still goes gray

Comment: did you also try injecting the iframe using javascript?

Comment: yes i did, i have created a javascript(with code injected) file and attached it main file.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is in that case, does the Codepen work fine on your end?

Comment: In that case I can only suggest you to try to find the differences between your code and the codepen or to expand the code in the question to show the problem. Perhaps also add a screenshot?

Comment: i have updated the question, it would be great if you help me out

Comment: works like a charm if I copy your code back into a codepen, only thing I can think of is to add the JavaScript inside a jQuery document ready function, e.g. `$(function() { ...all code... })`;

Comment: @ckuijjer I have a derivative question regarding your post. Thank you for steering me toward a better solution than the one I was considering. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46102000/extracting-sender-info-in-jquery-for-bootstrap-iframe-modal

Comment: @Adrian To be honest I wouldn’t know right now, it’s been quite a while since I’ve used jQuery (I’m one of those lucky guys who can use all the newer things like ES6, React, etc). I imagine I would add a click function to the buttons that would grab the data-source of the button and then does the trick above. Not sure about the syntax though :(

Comment: @ckuijjer Thanks for getting back to me...I can do it in Swift, Objective-C, but I'm having a heck of a time figuring it out on jQuery.