# Google maps embedding in a modal

Tags: google-maps, bootstrap-modal

I suppose We have a bug of google maps. When I embed iframe directly in a page, works fine. But in a bootstrap modal, its pointing wrong location. How can I fix this?

http://www.bootply.com/5VyAj2cAx0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use embed-responsive for your map div like this:

```
<div class="modal-body">
  <div class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
    <div id="map" class="embed-responsive-item"></div><p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Works out of the box without any additional javascript.

Demo: http://a0u.org/map_modal.html

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

It occurs because of modal rendered *`display:none`* property, javascripts in maps works wrong. if we create the iframe after modal shown, works fine.

This answer explains.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/27656177/5405168

Correct code is here:http://www.bootply.com/eLviOaNr5B